# Why hibernate PersistentSet.contains() is so slow? (compared to java.util.HashSet)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hashset

I'm developing a use case where I'm given a collection of IDs (named `group`) and need to verify which of these IDs are inside another collection (named `projectDevicesIds`) and which don't. Note that this last collection is a PersistentSet obtained from a database. The code is very simple as follow:

```
Collection<String> inside = new HashSet<>();
Collection<String> notInside = new HashSet<>();
group.forEach(id -> {
        if (projectDevicesIds.contains(id)) inside.add(id);
        else notInside.add(id);
    });
```

So far so good, the problem is when `projectDevicesIds` (hibernate PersistentSet) is 100 000 in size and `group` contains 1000 ids, this code takes an average of 200 ms to run. When I do the same test but instead of using a PersistentSet I use a HashSet it only takes 1 ms! Even if the test is not professionally accurate, this difference is insane and harms my use case performance. In hibernate [official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html) they say PersistentSet uses HashSet internally, so I was expecting about the same performance.

Can someone explain to me why PersistentSet.contains() takes so long comparing to HashSet? And help me in some way improving this use case performance?

Comment: Have you had a look at the SQL statements that Hibernate executes?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, the problem is not with SQL. As I said, before forEach(), if I convert PersistentSet to HashSet is takes only 1 ms. The problem is that conversion is heavy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PersistentSet represents an association on the database. This means that when you call `contains`, Hibernate ORM needs to first flush previous operations that might affect the association and eventually reload it from the database. Or it might need to just reload it if the association has been lazy loaded.

The difference in performance shouldn't be that high once the collection has been loaded the first time but it really depends from how you get the `projectDevicesIds`.

If you enable the log, you should see if Hibernate ORM needs to run additional queries when you call the `contains` method or not.

Comment: This is an isolated test, no operations are done simultaneously, so there is no need to flush or reload. `projectDevicesIds` is lazy-loaded however, I have logs enabled and the only query done is first loading this collection. The 200 ms time is only for the forEach() it doesn't count with collection loading.

Comment: I've changed the fetch type from `Lazy` to `Eager` and it takes now only 1 ms! Thank you,  I thought that after the lazy collection has been loaded to RAM it wouldn't impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

@Davide answer solved the `forEach` time problem (from 200ms to 1ms) however `eager` fetching turned out to be slower and the overall time (`eager fetch` + `forEach`) was higher ( > 250ms).

So I figured out a workaround to force using a `HashSet` (instead of a `PersistentSet`). Instead of getting the devices through `Project POJO`, in `ProjectJpaRepositoty` I added a custom SQL query to get devices id from a specific project, but the return class is a `HashSet`:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, String> {
            @Query(
                    value = "SELECT id FROM device WHERE project_id = :projectId",
                    nativeQuery = true
            )
            HashSet<String> getDevicesId(String projectId);
}
```

Now the overall time is the lowest I can get (~75ms), which is acceptable.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the original question (Why PersistentSet is slow?). Also I  doubt the problem is the PersistentSet. I think the reason is faster now is that you are getting the ids in a different way and this is saving you some time. It would be interesting to see what kind of query you where running before.